# Conversion of Qt Signals to Boost Signals2

Tags: c++, qt, boost

I have the following code that implements a Signal/Slot + Concurrency in Qt and was wondering if I can convert this to Boost/Threads and Boost/signal2

```
 void MyClass::Func1() 
 {
    emit ImplementingFunc1();
    //Do the stuff here
    Func1Implementation()

    QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(this, &MyClass::WaitForFunc1Finish());
 }

 void MyClass::WaitForFunc1Finish()
 {
    int result = GetResponse();

    emit Func1HasFinished();
 }
```

How can I implement the emit functions (in the above, these are slots in MyClass) and the pipeline using Boost?

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement your requirements using boost. However, the signals are different because boost does not give you an event loop to dispatch signals to slots.

It means that slot connected to a boost signal called a in thread will be executed **in that thread !**.

Roughly:

MyClass.h

```
typedef boost::signals2::signal<void ()> FinishedSig;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<FinishedSig> FinishedSigPtr;

typedef boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> LockGuard;

class MyClass
{
public:
    // Signal
    FinishedSig& finished() { return *m_sig; }
    void Func1();
    void WaitForFunc1Finish();
    void WaitForFunc1FinishSlot();

private:
    FinishedSigPtr m_sig;
    boost::mutex m_mutex;
    boost::thread m_thread;
}
```

MyClass.cpp

```
// Signal connection
this->finished().connect(boost::bind(&MyClass::Func1HasFinishedSlot, this));


void MyClass::Func1() 
{
//Do the stuff here
Func1Implementation()

m_thread = boost::thread(&MyClass::WaitForFunc1Finish, this);
}

void MyClass::WaitForFunc1Finish()
{
    LockGuard l(m_mutex);
    // Variables are guarded against concurrent access here
    int result = GetResponse();

    (*m_sig)(); // emit finished sig
}

void MyClass::Func1HasFinishedSlot()
{
    // This will be executed in the calling thread
    LockGuard l(m_mutex);
    // Variables are guarded against concurrent access here
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Kikohs, let me try this solution and get back to you. I am new to Boost and hence this question :)

Comment: Boost signals2 and thread are not easy. It is completely different from Qt and much more C++ oriented (aka template and stuff) than Qt. If you need to simulate a thread pool for your processing, there is also a way using Boost.Asio. Good luck.

Comment: I am aware of that after browsing through the net. Let me try this solution and see how it goes. I actually want to get away from Qt due to the "moc" process and restrict its use for GUI development only.

Comment: Kikohs, I do not see any definition for the Func1HasFinishedSlot() besides defining it in the class.